# Silent Backup? Or why is my updated answer not showing up?

Tags: support

Yesterday I updated [my answer concerning C# multi value dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10935485/303290) by adding a paragraph about the immutability of `Lookup` as suggested in a comment and how to workaround this by using alternatives like `MultiDictionary`.

However, now that I received an upvote for that I wanted to look at the updated answer of the person who commented - just to find out that not my updated version showed up but the previous one instead - while my "updated as requested" comment is this there. The edit log only shows 4 edit - yesterday I made the fifth.

Is there a reason why my update isn't there anymore? Silent restore from backup or something? Is that behaviour something I have to expect in the future?

I could easily write that paragraph from scratch but it wouldn't be exactly the same and I wanted to check that such edit resets don't happen too often before posting the update again.

**Update** I just re-updated my answer as I lost hope to get the old update restored. Also I think the current text is better than the previous version, so please don't restore the old version. I admit this is a bit confusing though.

Comment: My initial assumption would be [a PEBCAK error](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK). Are you sure you didn't possibly accidentally click "cancel", or close the page without actually submitting the edit? Did you check that the edit showed up after you submitted it?

Comment: @Dukeling I'm quite sure I did. Also, why whould I get 2 upvotes for the "updated" comment if the update was not commited.

Comment: What ever happened it isn't captured in your history either: https://stackoverflow.com/users/303290/mbx?tab=activity&sort=revisions nor in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10935485/timeline). Assuming you were not answer banned  at the moment only a dev could tell what went wrong, if anything did.